# Using a lambda for mechanism to find element in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, lambda, java-8

I have a snip code using lambda, but got error

> "target type of a lambda conversion must be an interface".

Anyone can help? My code is as follows:

```
private By optStarGrade = (strStar) -> { By.xpath("//input[@id='" + strStar + "'"); };
```

Answer (score 2):

`By` is a class, so it cannot be used as a target type for a lambda expression.

Only interfaces with a SAM (Single Abstract Method) can be used as target types for lambda expressions.

So, if you really wanted to use a lambda, then use a `Consumer<String>`:

```
private Consumer<String> optStarGrade = (strStar) -> {By.xpath("//input[@id='" + strStar + "'");};
```

if you don't want to ignore the returned value from `By.xpath` then use `Function<String, By>`

```
private Function<String, By> optStarGrade = (strStar) -> By.xpath("//input[@id='" + strStar + "'");
```

See the [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) and [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) functional interfaces  for more information.

Answer (score 1):

#### Method

To simplify what you probably are trying out and to correlate it better you can start off with your current code represented as a method. This method is trying to find a `optStarGrade` of type `By` for a given `strStar` which is a subpart of your `XPath`, which would look something like:

```
public static By optStarGradeFunction(String strStar) {
    return By.xpath("//input[@id='" + strStar + "'");
}
```

and then you can create the mechanism `By` as:

```
By optStarGrade = findByXPath("XPath");
```

---

#### Anonymous class

A similar representation of this method(a.k.a function) would be :

```
Function<String, By> optStarGradeFunction = new Function<String, By>() {
    @Override
    public By apply(String strStar) {
        return By.xpath("//input[@id='" + strStar + "'");
    }
};
```

and then accessible as

```
By optStarGrade = optStarGradeFunction.apply("XPath"); // calls the above 'apply' method
```

---

#### Lambda

But then, the `Function` could be represented using lambda as simple as :

```
Function<String, By> optStarGradeFunction = strStar -> By.xpath("//input[@id='" + strStar + "'");
```